# Bootstrap / Grid system?

Tags: html, css, gridview, bootstrap-4

im trying to start with bootstrap and having issues with the grid system.
i came across this block of code but dont understand those classes.Could someone simplify the idea and explanation behind this for me? maybe with some examples :P

ty very much 
~O.K

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- Start of the first row -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <p> Row 1, Cols 1-6 </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <p> Row 1, Cols 7-12 </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Start of the second row -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <p> Row 2, Cols 1-5 </p> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <p> Row 2, Cols 6-10 </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <p> Row 2, Cols 1-5 </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

They have pretty good documentation

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: Can you please close this question (set it as answered) so no body waste time trying to check it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Grid system, there are twelve(12) columns, you can divide your row in 12 parts.

in your code you have divided second row in 15 parts instead of 12 parts.

you can learn more from this site, https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

and also you can learn from bootstrap documentation site,

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

```
<div class="container">
  <!-- Start of the first row -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <p> Row 1, Cols 1-6 </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <p> Row 1, Cols 7-12 </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Start of the second row -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p> Row 2, Cols 1-5 </p> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p> Row 2, Cols 6-10 </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p> Row 2, Cols 1-5 </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

each row can have a maximum of 12 columns before it will force the next column to the next line. So the first row has two columns on the same line. The second row has 2 columns on the first line and one column on the second line.

breakdown of the class names: 
X stands for the screen size where this width is applied. Y stands for the number of colunms our of 12 this item will be given for its width. So if you gave one div the class names of "col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4" this div would take up the whole row at a screen size of 0"-medium, 1/2 of a row on medium-large screen, and 1/3 of a row at a screen size of large+